# Laravel 5.5 view composer never gets called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to implement a composer provider in Laravel 5.5 as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views

I've created a `ComposerServiceProvider` and added it to the `Config\App` providers array. I've created my `DashboardComposer`, which is added in the boot method of the `ComposerServiceProvider`, and I've returned the `$view` object with an array of data (cleverly called `$data`).

I'm getting an error when loading the dashboard view that the `$data` variable is undefined. When setting breakpoints and tracing the execution of the view render, the `ComposerServiceProvider` is never called, nor is the `DashboardComposer`.

Is there any common checklist of issues with creating a composer that I may be missing?

As requested here's the code in the `DashboardComposer`

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class DashboardComposer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $data = [
            'key' => 'value',
        ];

        $view->with('data', $data);
    }
}
```

and here's the `ComposerServiceProvider` boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer(
        'dashboard.index', DashboardComposer::class
    );
}
```

To be extra clear, my file I'm trying to serve with this composer's data is at `/resources/views/dashboard/index.blade.php`. I'm not totally clear on the view naming convention, but I believe that would make that `ViewComposer` find the correct file to serve.

Comment: Post your code where you set data using the view composer.

Comment: what is ` $data = [
            'key' => 'value',
        ];` are you passing any data ?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi-- that's exactly what I'm passing. Just something to prove that it's working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you associated the composer file with the dashboard view in the `ComposerServiceProvider`?

```
View::composer(
    'dashboard', DashboardComposer::class
);
```

Try registering a closure instead of using the class in the boot method to see if you're at least getting that far:

```
View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
        $view->with('data', $data);
 });
```

Last thing, try returning the data as an array like:

```
$view->with(['data' => $data]);
```

Edit:

I believe it's due to your filename. `'dashboard.index'` is looking for `index.blade.php` in the dashboard directory. Rename your file to `dashboard.blade.php`.

Comment: Thanks @btl-- I'll give your suggestions a try, but xdebug isn't breaking anywhere in the `DashboardComposer` or in the `ComposerServiceProvider`, which makes me think it's not trying to call the composer at all

Comment: Yes it appears the problem is the filename as suggested.